# how to convert to json based on the number of elements in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following flat array

```
let data = [
    ["0000001", "PAUL", "Y", "PELUCHE", "DRAKE", "DOG"],
    ["0000002", "ECHEBEL", "Y", "CAT", ""],
    ["0000003", "NANCY", "Y", "FERRET", "HAMSTER", ""]
]
```

I'm reading a .txt, where I get n amount of records per row, but logically, I need to convert to json, because it is easier for me to work with key: value

```
let orderData = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  let id = b[0]
  id = parseInt(b[0])
  let name = b[1]
  let pets = b.splice(3)

  if (!a.hasOwnProperty(id)) a[id] = {
    name: "",
    pets: []
  }

  a[id].name = name

  a[id].pets.push(...pets.filter(x => x !== ""))

  return a
}, {})
console.log(orderData)

Object.keys(orderData).forEach(key => {

let objeto = orderData[key]

objeto.pets.forEach(pet => console.log(objeto.name, pet))
})
```

But that's wrong, because it doesn't let me convert the id to int, and even though it prints the amount, it returns it as a flat array and I would like it to return something like this please
also, that it is instantiating from the id, how do I include the id also within the same js object and do something like this

desired output:

```
{"id":1, "name":"PAUL","PET1":"PELUCHE"},
{"id":1, "name":"PAUL","PET2":"DRAKE"},
{"id":1, "name":"PAUL","PET3":"DOG"},
{"id":2, "name":"ECHEBEL","PET1":"CAT"},
{"id":3, "name":"NACY","PET1":"FERRET" },
{"id":3, "name":"NANCY","PET2":"HAMSTER"}
```

output receibed:

```
{
  '1': { name: 'PAUL', pets: [ 'PELUCHE', 'DRAKE', 'DOG' ] },
  '2': { name: 'ECHEBEL', pets: [ 'CAT' ] },
  '3': { name: 'NANCY', pets: [ 'FERRET', 'HAMSTER' ] }
}
  PAUL PELUCHE
  PAUL DRAKE
  PAUL DOG
  ECHEBEL CAT
  NANCY FERRET
  NANCY HAMSTER
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output youre expecting?

Comment: edited! brother @HanYolo

Comment: So just put `a[id].id = id`?

Comment: Thanks, but it's like this in the third box with the set of jsons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my two cents:

```js
function petFilter(array){
  let a, n, o, r = [];
  for(let z=0,c=1,q=array.length; z<q; z++,c++){
    a = array[z]; n = a.splice(1, 1)[0]; a.splice(0, 2);
    for(let i=0,m=1,v,l=a.length; i<l; i++,m++){
      v = a[i]; 
      if(v !== '')r.push({id:c, name:n, ['PET'+m]:v});
    }
  }
  return r;
}
let data = [
  ["0000001", "PAUL", "Y", "PELUCHE", "DRAKE", "DOG"],
  ["0000002", "ECHEBEL", "Y", "CAT", ""],
  ["0000003", "NANCY", "Y", "FERRET", "HAMSTER", ""]
];
console.log(petFilter(data));
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much !! <3. <3 How do you remove the empty strings?

Comment: I fixed the empties.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think what you're asking is to add the id inside the object, and your desired result is an object array so I added a result variable

```
    let data = [
    ["0000001", "PAUL", "Y", "PELUCHE", "DRAKE", "DOG"],
    ["0000002", "ECHEBEL", "Y", "CAT", ""],
    ["0000003", "NANCY", "Y", "FERRET", "HAMSTER", ""]
]
let orderData = data.reduce((a, b) => {
  let id = b[0]
  id = parseInt(b[0])
  let name = b[1]
  let pets = b.splice(3)

  if (!a.hasOwnProperty(id)) 
  a[id] = {
    id: id,
    name: "",
    pets: []
  }

  a[id].name = name

  a[id].pets.push(...pets.filter(x => x !== ""))

  return a
}, {})
console.log("orderData")
console.log(orderData)

let result = []
Object.keys(orderData).forEach(key => {
let objeto = orderData[key]

    let i = 1
objeto.pets.forEach(pet => {
    let petNum = "PET" + i++
    let petName = pet
    
    let temp = {
        "id": objeto.id,
        "name": objeto.name,
        };
        temp[petNum] = petName
    
    result.push(temp)
    })
})
console.log(result)
```

Output:

```
{id: 1, name: "PAUL", PET1: "PELUCHE"}
{id: 1, name: "PAUL", PET2: "DRAKE"}
{id: 1, name: "PAUL", PET3: "DOG"}
{id: 2, name: "ECHEBEL", PET1: "CAT"}
{id: 3, name: "NANCY", PET1: "FERRET"}
{id: 3, name: "NANCY", PET2: "HAMSTER"}
```

Comment: I do not set the output as in the "desired output" box 
Thank you as well

Comment: Updated answer so it reflects expected result

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
let data = [
    ["0000001", "PAUL", "Y", "PELUCHE", "DRAKE", "DOG"],
    ["0000002", "ECHEBEL", "Y", "CAT", ""],
    ["0000003", "NANCY", "Y", "FERRET", "HAMSTER", ""]
];

const entries = data
  .map((n) => {
     const [id, name, flag, ...pets] = n;
    
      return [
        Number(id),
        { id, name, pets, flag }
      ];
  });
  
const result = Object.fromEntries(entries);  

console.log(result);

Object
  .entries(result)
  .forEach((kv) => {
     kv[1].pets.forEach((pet) => {
       if (pet !== "") {
         console.log(kv[1].name, pet);
       }
    });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0z5athdw/1/

Comment: Thanks brother, but not because you are taking the id as the identifier, that is, is there another way to do it, which returns me in the way I put it in the space before the output? @

Comment: Im having trouble understanding the request. You need the pet owner printed?

Comment: I do not set the output as in the "desired output" box